# Conditional Running Total with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with 2 columns: **ID** and **Numbers**; and I want to create a new column **Result** with the running total of the Numbers column but every time the running total surpass 20, the running total should be restarted. Also, if the running total is lower than 20, the result should not be displayed. This have to be done using DAX only.

Thanks in advice.

Note: the **Conditional Running Total** column exist just to show how the running total works.

| ID | Numbers | ConditionalRunningTotal | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 9 |  |
| 2 | 7 | 16 |  |
| 3 | 9 | 25 | 25 |
| 4 | 8 | 8 |  |
| 5 | 9 | 17 |  |
| 6 | 9 | 26 | 26 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 8 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 9 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 10 | 9 | 10 |  |
| 11 | 9 | 19 |  |
| 12 | 2 | 21 | 21 |
| 13 | 1 | 1 |  |

Eddit: I added couple more rows to test the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I test this only on your sample data, there may be some errors in logic. I split this to several column, for better understanding of what i doing.

```
Running = var _curID = 'Table'[ID]
var _run = CALCULATE( sum('Table'[Numbers]), FILTER(all('Table'),  'Table'[ID] <= _curID)) 
return

ceiling(floor(ceiling(_run , 5) -
ceiling(MOD(_run, 5), 20), 15)
, 20) /20

Rung = var _curID = 'Table'[ID]
var  _previousDate = CALCULATE( max('Table'[Running]), FILTER('Table', 'Table'[ID] < EARLIER('Table'[ID])))
return
_previousDate+0


Final = var _id = [ID]
var _Rung = [Rung]
var _ret = 
CALCULATE( sum('Table'[Numbers]), filter(ALL('Table'), [ID] <= _id && _Rung = [Rung]))
return
if (_ret > 20, _ret, 0)
```

Final output:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your logic. Change the 9 for ID3 to 100; the result for ID6 should still be 26.

Comment: Indeed, the logic seems to work at first but when testing with a larger table it stop working. I added a couple more rows to the sample table. However I'm impressed on how you managed to come with that crazy dax function.

Comment: The hardest part is finding the appropriate logic for computing the intervals. Unfortunately, I do not currently have any additional tips to improve the calculation.

Comment: I don't think it will ever be possible to define a logic to account for intervals of arbitrary length. A recursive set-up would appear to be the only option, though it's well-known how difficult this is to implement using DAX.