# DAX PATH function with table variable

Tags: powerbi, dax

In DAX, the `PATH` function requires parameters which are column references. In the example below, I can use a `PATH` function referring to the "ID" and "ParentID" columns which are statically defined in the DEFINE statement.

```
DEFINE
TABLE MyTable = UNION (
    ROW ( "ID", 1, "ParentID", BLANK ( ) ),
    ROW ( "ID", 2, "ParentID", 1 ),
    ROW ( "ID", 3, "ParentID", 1 ),
    ROW ( "ID", 4, "ParentID", 2 )
)

EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
    MyTable,
    "Path", PATH ( MyTable[ID], MyTable[ParentID] )
)

-- Result
-- ID  ParentID   Path
--  1     BLANK      1
--  2         1    1|2
--  3         1    1|3
--  4         2  1|2|4
```

My question is how I can refer to columns created dynamically in a table variable? With the below query, I get an error saying that the MyTableVar is not found.

```
EVALUATE
VAR MyTableVar = UNION (
    ROW ( "ID", 1, "ParentID", BLANK ( ) ),
    ROW ( "ID", 2, "ParentID", 1 ),
    ROW ( "ID", 3, "ParentID", 1 ),
    ROW ( "ID", 4, "ParentID", 2 )
)
RETURN ADDCOLUMNS (
    MyTableVar,
    "Path", PATH ( MyTableVar[ID], MyTableVar[ParentID] )  -- Error: MyTableVar is not found
)
```

I also tried `PATH ( [ID], [ParentID] )`, but the error message says [ID] is not a valid reference to a table column.

I researched several articles but could not find a solution.

- [Microsoft Docs - PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/path-function-dax)
- [DAX GUIDE - PATH](https://dax.guide/path/)
- [Microsoft Docs - Column and measure references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-column-measure-references)
- [SQLBI - Table and column references using DAX variables](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/table-and-column-references-using-dax-variables/)
- [Microsoft Power BI Community Forum - DAX: Is it possible to refer to columns of a table variable?](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-Is-it-possible-to-refer-to-columns-of-a-table-variable/m-p/568045#M268124)

Comment: As far as I know, this is not currently feasible with a table variable. Maybe there is another way to get the result you want. What do you want to use the PATH for?

Comment: Thanks @msta42a for the comment. I wanted to use this to implement a dynamic programming algorithm to solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71002626/conditional-running-total-with-dax

Comment: i answer "this"  problem.